# Why are mongoose query result objects so verbose in new version?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I installed my dependencies on a new computer and it must have updated mongoose.
All my informative results from queries have returned into these messes with a lot of information that may be useful at times but generally is not useful. Very verbose.

So for example when it runs console.log(result) in a query promise, it used to return something like this:

```
user: {
    _id: '2c918aa5-3d5f-4397-8dd9-35c3675f53a2',
    email: 'ayeman@gmail.com',
    username: 'ayeman',
    password: '$2b$10$1sBah/12s12Ox0971221nk5g2s12s11FVRCW',
    watching: '',
    __v: 0
}
```

instead now it returns this:

```
model {
  '$__': InternalCache {
    strictMode: true,
    selected: {},
    shardval: undefined,

    .....

    *200 plus lines of verbose data*

    ....

      remove: [Function: pull],
      _path: 'chats',
      isMongooseArray: true,
      validators: [],
      _schema: [SchemaArray]
    ],
    _id: '2c918aa5-3d5f-4397-8dd9-35c3675f53a2',
    email: 'ayeman@gmail.com',
    username: 'ayeman',
    password: '$2b$10$1sBah/12s12Ox0971221nk5g2s12s11FVRCW',
    watching: '',
    __v: 0
  },
  '$init': true
}
```

I cant for the life of me find the documentation to return it to the old style.

It seems silly to find all my console logs and cut the extra data manually.
Is there a method to change this back? I was looking for something like mongoose.model.options.changeResultsStyle() or something but I cannot find anything

Comment: have you tried `.lean()` to turn your result object into a json blob?

Comment: Just discovered it a couple seconds ago. It seems as if the old mongoose defaulted to .lean(); This way is actually better since that info might be relevant in some scenarios. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

In the new mongoose version it seems as if it defaults to verbose results. Using .lean() on mongoose query methods will return the lean style that the old mongoose version defaulted too.

My example scenario

```
User.findOne({username: req.body.username }, {friends: 1}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result.friends[1].pending)
    res.json(result.friends[1].pending);
}).lean();
```

{
  _id: '2c918aa5-3d5f-4397-8dd9-35c3675f53a2',
  friends: [ { confirmed: [Array] }, { pending: [Array] } ],
  status: 'offline',
  chats: [ { confirmed: [Array] }, { pending: [Array] } ],
  email: 'ayeman@gmail.com',
  username: 'ayeman',
  password: '$2b$10$gq0OrbxulaUBah/O.LhfjuiOx0970brivNStLXnk5gGn0QYRFVRCW',
  watching: '',
  __v: 0
}